# preg_match unconditionally return key for unmatched optional capture group

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$pattern = "/^(?<animal>DOG|CAT)?(?<color>BLUE|RED)?$/i";
$str = "DOG";

preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
$matches = array_filter($matches, 'is_string', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);


// $str = "dog" returns [animal] => DOG

//$str = "dogBLUE" returns [animal] => dog and [color] => BLUE
print_r($matches);
```

I have an example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2428bc68adcf9929557d86dc1ae72552c3681b58 too

Both named capture groups are optional and so `keys` will only be returned if a match is found.

## My Question

How can I unconditionally return keys for any of my possible named capture groups? Empty String '' would be great if it group ain't found.

Input of "DOG" resulting in `[animal] => 'DOG', [color] => ''` is what I'm looking for.

I was hoping for a flag on `preg_match` to do this, but couldn't find anything.

**Update:** I just want to avoid doing `isset($matches[OPTIONAL_GROUP])`

Thanks!

Comment: With `$pattern = "/^(?<animal>DOG|CAT|)(?<color>BLUE|RED|)$/i";`?

Comment: haha, I guess my example was too simple. I have other complex scenarios where I need optional groups.

Comment: Then please check [this solution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#112446).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Feel free to post as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow duplicate named captures (with J or with `(?J)` for PHP < 7.3) and initialize groups you need at the start of the pattern:

```
~ (?<animal>) (?<color>)
  
  ^ (?<animal>DOG|CAT)? (?<color>RED|BLUE)? $
~xiJ
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/s5QRi)

Advantage: you can choose the order of groups in the result array.

---

Or without to change your pattern:

```
$arr = ['animal' => '', 'color' => ''];

$result = array_intersect_key($matches, $arr) + $arr;
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/9Ci3u)

Notice: `array_intersect_key($matches + $arr, $arr)` produces exactly the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [andre at koethur dot de's solution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#112446):

```php
$pattern = "/^(?<animal>DOG|CAT)?(?<color>BLUE|RED)?$/i";
$str = "DOG";

if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
  $matches = array_merge(array('animal' => '', 'color' => ''), $matches);
  $matches = array_filter($matches, 'is_string', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
  print_r($matches);
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/nL07C).
Output:

```
Array
(
    [animal] => DOG
    [color] => 
)
```

The idea is that you need to "assign a name to all subpatterns you are interested in, and merge `$matches` afterwards with an constant array containing some reasonable default values".